# Fortran 90 array subsets

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am trying to read some Fortran code but there is something I can't understand with array subsets operations like this one

Assume `n = 3`

And the arrays

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12)
REAL(KIND=dp)   :: P(n+1),P0(n)
```

what does this line exactly do?

```
DO i=1,n-1
  …..
  P(3:i+2) = P(3:i+2) - i*P0(1:i) / (i+1)
  ….
END DO
```

Is it a nested loop? Like `j` from `3` to `i+2` for `P` and `k` from `1` to `i` for `P0`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Take the line

```
P(3:i+2) = P(3:i+2) - i*P0(1:i) / (i+1)
```

and replace `i` with `1` (the first value it takes in the `do` loop)

```
P(3:3) = P(3:3) - 1*P0(1:1) / 2
```

On the lhs you have a *slice* (or section) of array `P` from element 3 to element 3, so in this case just one element -- but still an array slice not a scalar.  This is updated by subtracting `1` times the (same sized) slice of array `P0` and divided by 2.

It's a bit more interesting in the next iteration, with `i==2` and

```
P(3:4) = P(3:4) - 2*P0(1:2) / 3
```

where the array slices are now 2 elements each.  The operations on array slices are applied on corresponding elements from each array so this statement is approximately equivalent to the two statements

```
P(3) = P(3) - 2*P0(1) / 3
P(4) = P(4) - 2*P0(2) / 3
```

It's better to think of this in Fortran terms, as operations on array sections, than as some kind of syntactic sugar for nested loops.